# Flutter: Update class variable when global variable changes with MVVM

Tags: flutter, mvvm, state-management

I have my app setup in such a way that a `SessionRepository` provider wraps the MaterialApp. This repository allows me to track data about the session throughout the app.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<SessionRepository>(
      create: (_) => SessionRepository()),
      child: MaterialApp(
        ...
      ),
    );
  }
```

In one of my screens, I create a view model as I'm following MVVM architecture, and use the `SessionRepository` to initialize some view model variables.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final session = Provider.of<SessionRepository>(context, listen: false);

    return Provider<TestViewModel>(
      create: (context) => TestViewModel(session),
      child: ...
    );
}
```

In my view model this is happening:

```
class TestViewModel{
  final SessionRepository session;
  final var foo;
  final var bar;

  TestViewModel(this.session) : foo = session.foo, bar = session.bar;
}
```

My question is that whenever I update the session variables, I also want the view model to store the updated variables. I can't think of any way that this could be done automatically when updating the session, any inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to notify your view , when SessionRepository property change , and recreate your  viewmodel with new values, SessionRepository  must implement [ChangeNotifier](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier-class.html). Check out the [ChangeNotifierProvider](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/ChangeNotifierProvider-class.html) samples.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but isn't it expensive to rebuild the whole material app whenever i update a session variable?

Comment: Provider only builds widgets where you retrive to SessionRepository like this Provider.of<SessionRepository>(context, listen: true);